# phpunit with codeigniter3 in ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter 3 and I installed phpunit in ubuntu but not able to use the classes of phpunit getting fatal error.

Now i want to check whether phpunit correctly installed or not?

If installed then how to use it in codeigniter application?

Comment: Could you post the error which you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate PHPUnit with CodeIgniter using CIUnit. For more details on why CIUnit is required go through:

[Why is CIUnit needed in order to use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345667/why-is-ciunit-needed-in-order-to-use-phpunit-with-codeigniter)

To know more about CIUnit visit:
https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit/overview

Sample code to integrate codeIgniter(3) with PHPUnit:
[How do I use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395147/how-do-i-use-phpunit-with-codeigniter)

and this also may help you
[How do I use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122397/how-do-i-use-phpunit-with-codeigniter-3)

Comment: And one more useful link :https://github.com/willmendesneto/Codeigniter-TDD-with-Hooks